# How to post to a facebook fan page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I am trying to post to a facebook fan page via my website but it only allows me to post to my actual profile page.

here is my code that is working( it post to profile page ) but not to the fan page, i only want to post this to the fan page . How can i do this?

```
<a
id="fb-share"
style='text-decoration:none;'
type="icon_link"
onClick="window.open(
    'http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]='
        + 'YOUR_DESCRIPTION&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images][0]=YOUR_IMAGE',
    'sharer',
    'toolbar=0,status=0,width=580,height=325');"
href="javascript: void(0)"
```

> Post to facebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only post `"on a page you manage"`, as it say in the sharer.php select. Make sure to select the Page where it says "Posting as" too, if you want to post "as Page". Else it will get posted "as User".

Also, sharer.php only takes the URL as parameter and reads the rest of the data from the Open Graph tags. You can´t use title, image and other parameters anymore.